# Refreshing a fragment view from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I currently have an app that has 4 tabs (fragments). They are fragments A,B,C,D, in that order.

Fragment A is the first view opened (along with B because viewPager loads the view before and after the current view).

When I click a button in Fragment A, it sends Data back to MainActivity and then sends that data out to Fragments B and C.

However, this is where the issue comes into play. Since Fragment B was already called, the View isn't updated once I click the button and send the data over, but Fragment C is because the view wasn't called before.

Is there any way that I can remedy this?

Comment: which methodology are you following to communicate between fragments??

Comment: I hope you're using Interface to communicate btwn the fragments. If so, try to use `viewpager.invalidate()` and `viewpager.notifyDataSetChanged()`. It would help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it a few ways right.

1. Just set the data to the fragment and have it update its views
2. Have all the fragments like B and C register themselves to recieve data from the MainActivity and when MainActivity gets it's data set you tell all the registered receivers of the new data
3. Recreate the fragment
4. Use an event bus and tell all subsribers of the new data and MainActivity, Fragment B would get notified of new data. Fragment C would get its data when created by MainActivity

I think this list is pretty endless tbh

The key here is the fragments need to fetch the data from the actvitiy aswell as be updated by the activity. In which case you need to break your UI update behaviour out of onCreateView and into its own updateUI() function. updateUI(MyData) can then be called from onCreateView and also called in a setMyData() on the fragment. Just make sure you check the isAdded flag in setMyData.

This pretty much says it all:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple fragment communicator that allows the activity to call the fragment, and the same for a fragment to talk to the activity.

You can change the views with the new data based on calling the method from within the activity. The way I do it is set the fragments in the activity then pass them into the page adapter this way I can call the methods within the fragment and implement the fragmentcommunicator interface on the fragments.

You can honestly even avoid the interface if you want, but if you are going to include the same method in all the fragments to talk to them it is easiest.

If you show code, I can show you a quick example.